# User in "dbAdmin" role cannot even do a find?

Tags: mongodb

I set up a user in my "stocks" database intending this user to be able to fully administer the collections and indexes in the stocks database.

```
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> use stocks
switched to db stocks
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> db.addUser( { user : "stocks", pwd : "b0nd5", roles : [ "dbOwner", "backup", "restore" ] } );
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("537bb7d963095ee3392c552e"), "user" : "stocks", "pwd" : "24efdd0922a7c949e1e9c355e7d7648c", "roles" : [  "dbOwner",  "backup",  "restore" ] }
```

If I understand MongoDB's "built in roles" correctly (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/) setting this guy as "dbOwner" should have granted me these priviledges on the "stocks" database.

Mongo Shelling in as this user, however, shows that I can't do anything.  I can't find, I can't insert, all I can do is shell in.  Arghhhh.  Where did I go wrong.  Does the "dbOwner" role not really grant me all the access I need on the database I put my user into?

```
bobk-mbp:~ bobk$ mongo -u stocks -p 'b0nd5' localhost/stocks
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: localhost/stocks
> db
stocks
> db.bob.find()
error: { "$err" : "not authorized for query on stocks.bob", "code" : 16550 }
>
```

I am operating a Mongo 2.4.6 replica set.

Comment: Its looking like this is a Mongo 2.4.6 to 2.6.x issue in that the "dbOwner" role does not appear to exist in 2.4.6.  I've dropped and re-added by user as roles : [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin", "userAdmin", "backup", "restore" ] and my restore, at least, is making progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "dbOwner" role doesn't exist at Mongo 2.4.6.  Adding the component roles of "readWrite", "dbAdmin", "userAdmin" to the roles fixes the issue.

```
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> use stocks
switched to db stocks
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> db.addUser( {
  user : "stocks", 
  pwd : "b0nd5", 
  roles : [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin", "userAdmin", "backup", "restore" ]
} );
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> db.system.users.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537bc4d563095ee3392c5531"),
    "user" : "stocks",
    "pwd" : "24efdd0922a7c949e1e9c355e7d7648c",
    "roles" : [
            "readWrite",
            "dbAdmin",
            "userAdmin",
            "backup",
            "restore"
    ]
}
```